# Projection of a ball in the ambient space to a manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Let $B_h (x)$ be the ball of radius $0<h \ll 1$ centered at $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Let $I=[0,1]^{d-1}$ be the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$, and let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function. Then $$M:\,=\left\{(x,f(x)) ~ ~ | ~ ~ x\in I \right\} \, ,$$

is a $d-1$ dimensional manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

**My questions:**

1. Is $B_h (x) \cap M$ contained in a $d-1$ dimensional ball on $M$ with radius $O(h)$ as $h\to 0$, in the manifold's induced Riemannian metric?
2. Let $\sigma $ be the surface-measure on $M$ induced by the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Is $\sigma \left( B_h (x) \cap M\right) = O(h)$ as $h\to 0$? Is it $O(h^{d-1})$?
3. If one of the above answers are "no", what do we need to demand on $f$ to amend it? A finite curvature of $M$?

Intuitively, I think that both answers should be yes because (somehow) $M$ should have a bounded curvature. But I wasn't able to prove it. A *reference* would be also as useful.

(Cross-posted from [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842676/reference-small-balls-on-a-smooth-functions-graph), after 10 days of virtually no activity)

Comment: In question 1, presumably "in the manifold's metric" pertains to "radius", not to "ball". In other words, you don't expect $B_h(x)\cap M$ to be exactly a metric ball.  In (2), $O(h^{d-1})$ looks plausible. $O(h)$ does not; just consider what happens when $f$ is linear.

Comment: By "the manifold's metric" you could mean the induced metric as a subset of a metric space (i.e. a subset of Euclidean space with Euclidean metric), in which case the answer to question 1 is clearly yes. You could mean the induced Riemannian metric, as a submanifold with boundary and corners of a Riemannian manifold (Euclidean space with its standard Riemannian metric). Then question 1 has answer no: make the graph wiggle wildly up and down.

Comment: @BenMcKay: If $\nabla f$ is continuous, then the intrinsic distance on the graph is comparable with the Euclidean, is it not? Or perhaps what you meant is that there is no uniform bound (w.r.t. $f$)?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: I agree. I am not clear what being a ball as $h \to 0$ means, so I thought of it as being a ball for all small enough $h$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You're right about question 1, I've refined it accordingly. As for (2), If $h\to 0$, if its $O(h^{d-1})$ than it's surely $O(h)$

Comment: @BenMcKay Thanks for the comments. (1) I meant the Riemannian metric (I edited accordingly). (2) Mateusz comment is what  I was thinking. $\nabla f$ being continuous on compact sets should be enough for the graph to not wiggle to much. That is my intuition, but I can't make it precise. (3) Think of a series of ballse $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)$, that is what I mean by $h\to 0$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki If we take a "large" close ball, say $B_{\frac{1}{2}}(x)$, then within there is a uniform bound on $\nabla f$. Hence, for all smaller balls $B_h (x)$ with $h<\frac{1}{2}$, the same bound holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *induced Riemannian metric* refers to the (Euclidean) length $d(x, y)$ of the shortest path contained in $M$ with given endpoints $x, y$, then this is a completely elementary question. Or, I have misunderstood the problem completely: in this case let me know and I will delete this answer.

---

Clearly, $d(x, y) \geqslant |x - y|$. On the other hand, set $x = (\tilde{x}, f(\tilde{x}))$ and $y = (\tilde{y}, f(\tilde{y}))$, and define $L = |\tilde{y} - \tilde{x}|$ and $\tilde{z} = (\tilde{y} - \tilde{x}) / L$. We have
$$ d(x, y) \leqslant \int_0^L \sqrt{1 + (D_{\tilde{z}} f(\tilde{x} + t \tilde{z}))^2} dt \leqslant \sqrt{1 + \|\nabla f\|_\infty^2} \times L,$$
where $D_{\tilde{z}}$ is the directional derivative. Therefore,
$$ |x - y| \leqslant d(x, y) \leqslant \sqrt{1 + \|\nabla f\|_\infty^2} \times |x - y| . $$
This gives an affirmative answer to question 1.

Similarly, the volume element of $M$ is given by $$\sqrt{1 + |\nabla f(\tilde{x})|^2} d\tilde{x},$$ and so it is uniformly comparable with $d\tilde{x}$. It follows that the answer to question 2 is also 'yes'.

Comment: Thanks! So (1) We only need to require that $\nabla f \in L^{\infty}$. So, on a compact set, $C^2$ stronger than necessary? (2) The left-hand side inequality $d(x,y)\leq \int _0 ^L \sqrt{1+\ldots }$, where does it come from?

Comment: @AmirSagiv: (1) I think so. (2) $d(x,y)$ is the infimum over all paths, the integral in the right-hand side is the length of the path $(\tilde{x} + t \tilde{z}, f(\tilde{x} + t \tilde{z})$, $t \in [0, L]$.